# Multiple woocommerce single-product templates?

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce, woocommerce

I am building a shop that sells kiteboarding equipment. Some items are simple with just a thumbnail and description, and some are complex with custom options.

I would like to have two single-product templates. One for custom products, and one for simple products.

You can see at [development.ride-engine.com/shop/](http://development.ride-engine.com/shop/) I have the custom harnesses category and boards and accessories. Here is the [archive.php](http://pastebin.com/QsdswCb5) where I have two loops that display the items.

I would like the first loop to send a user to the custom template, and the second to the simple template. Is this possible? Where do I begin?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

I have used this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/single-post-template/ in the past and works very well.

Not tried it in woocommerce though... I dont see why it wouldn't work

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, tried it, no dice. The products aren't posts. Did give me an idea though that another solution would be to have different templates for different categories - but not sure how to do that either!

Answer (score 0):

After clicking a product from "archive.php" template file, you can then filter the products category at "single-product.php" (where the single product is displayed) and load a different template based on your category.

FYI, "single-product.php" also loads different template part at this line:

```
<?php woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); ?>
```

so choose where you want to override. :)